# Why are the disassemblies of these two simple statements slightly different?

Tags: c#, assembly

I wrote two simple programs that store the same integer value to two different variables, and I'm wondering why the disassembly is slightly different between both programs.

First program:

```
int y;
int x = (y = 2);
```

Disassembly:

```
0000003a  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],2 
00000041  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
00000044  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax
```

Second program:

```
int x = 2, y = 2;
```

Disassembly:

```
0000003a  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],2 
00000041  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],2
```

The second line in the first program, which is clearly the only change, simply copies the value pointed to by `[ebp-40h]` into the `eax` registry, right? Maybe it's a dumb question, but why are these slightly different? I'm not very familiar with assembly, to say the least, so I take it that you have to move a value into a registry before pointing to it? (or whatever the third line does. I think it's pointing...)

For the sake of readability, I plan to never instantiate variables in serious code like I did in the first program.

#### Edit

Per the discussion in the comments, I compiled Release builds of these two snippets instead of the Debug builds I had been using before. The results are virtually identical:

First program:

```
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        eax 
00000004  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
00000007  cmp         dword ptr ds:[005E14B4h],0 
0000000e  je          00000015 
00000010  call        6C37403F 
00000015  nop 
00000016  mov         esp,ebp 
00000018  pop         ebp 
00000019  ret
```

Second program:

```
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        eax 
00000004  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
00000007  cmp         dword ptr ds:[005514B4h],0 
0000000e  je          00000015 
00000010  call        6C42403F 
00000015  nop 
00000016  mov         esp,ebp 
00000018  pop         ebp 
00000019  ret
```

It looks like the differences are only in memory addresses (i.e. not really a difference). I think that's the correct interpretation, at any rate.

Comment: Is that disassembly a Debug build or Release?  I suspect that optimization, if enabled, might simplify the first version.

Comment: It's a debug build. I'll try it in a release build with optimisations when I'm back at the office.

Comment: If you don't ask the compiler to optimize, the result can be, eh, less well optimized.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano did you have a chance to check this with a release build?  I'm curious...

Comment: @phoog Thanks for reminding me. Should I just edit the results into my question? Apart from different memory addresses (which is to be expected), the results are identical in a release build.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano that's interesting.  I would edit the question if I were you.  One thing, though: when you start a release build in the Visual Studio debugger, the JIT compiler behaves a little differently; some optimizations are disabled.  The true test would be to start the application directly, and, after the method is JIT compiled, attach the debugger.

Comment: @phoog I'm not entirely sure how to do what you describe, but I'll edit my question to add the relevant disassemblies from a Release build.

Comment: @phoog I added the information. Please feel free to edit my question if I didn't present the new info properly.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano but the release build doesn't use the value 2 at all!  The variables have been optimized away.  I will try to devise a program that will keep them.

Comment: @phoog I hadn't noticed that. Programming isn't my speciality to begin with, and least of all assembly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example is rewritten to:

```
y = 2;
x = y;
```

because

```
(y = 2)
```

"evaluates" to

```
y
```

after assigning `y`.

And that matches the disassembly 1:1.

Sidenote: You can see the same effect with properties:

```
Button b;
b.Width = b.Height = 100; //inefficient!
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Just wanted to satisfy my curiosity at the end of the work day!